# CUDA: How does Thrust manage memory when using a Comparator in a sorting function?

Tags: sorting, cuda, thrust, gpu

I have a `char array` of 10 characters that I would like to pass as an argument to a comparator which will be used by Thrust's sorting function.

In order to allocate memory for this array I use `cudaMalloc`. However `cudaMalloc` allocates memory in the global memory, so whenever a thread wants to read data from this array it will have to access the global memory.

but this array is small and I believe it would be more efficient if it was stored into some shared memory or even in the registers of each thread. However is it possible to achieve this with Thrust and if yes how?

Here is the comparator:

```
struct comp{
   int *data_to_sort;
   char *helpingArray;

   comp(int *data_ptr) this->data_to_sort = data_ptr;

   __host__ __device__
      bool operator()(const int&a, const int&b){

            //use helpingArray to do some comparisons and
           // return true/false accordingly

      }
 }
```

then I allocate memory for the `helpingArray` in the global memory and pass it as an argument with the `Comparator` struct to the sorting function.

Note that the `data_to_sort` array is stored in the global memory because it contains the data that needs to be sorted, we can't avoid this from happening.

This works fine, and the sorting method is faster than the cpu sorting method, however I believe if I avoid storing the `helpingArray` in the global memory the sorting method will become much faster.

Comment: by the way, this char array is read only memory.

Comment: What is the access pattern of `helpingArray`? Is it random, or will each thread access it in a uniform way?

Comment: each thread will have to access at most all elements of `helpingArray`. It depends on what are the values of the data array, however assume that each thread accesses all elements one by one.

I've read about texture memory and since my data is read only, maybe I could benefit from it?

Comment: I believe using a shared memory would be better in this case, however I have no idea how I can tell Thrust to send this data to the shared memory of each block.

Comment: I think you could probably use `__constant__` memory which might take advantage of the constant cache.  I think that is why @talonmies is asking about the access pattern.  I don't know how to tell thrust to put something in shared memory.  Thrust isn't really managing your functor other than to treat it as a black box.  The only thing thrust really knows about is the comparator function entry point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree that putting `helpingArray` into global memory makes little sense and is reducing  performance to at least some degree. The thrust back-end which executes kernels is "closed" and doesn't expose kernel level features like shared memory or registers, so those can't be directly used.

Having said that, there are probably two things you can do to improve this. The first would be to declare your functor like this:

```
struct comp{
   char helpingArray[10];

   __host__ __device__
      bool operator()(const int&a, const int&b){ ... }
 }
```

You can populate `helpingArray` in host code before passing the functor to thrust algorithm you are using (note that the functor is passed by *value* so this is perfectly legal). In such a case, `helpingArray` probably winds up in thread local memory. There may or may not be a performance improvement in doing so. Certainly it greatly simplifies the host code required to support things.

The other alternative is to declare `helpingArray` in __constant__ memory and just refer to it inside the functor. *If* the access pattern of each thread is uniform, then there could be a performance improvement in doing so because of the constant cache.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, using the first approach for some reason made the code slower. I created a `comp c(...)` variable, populated the helpingArray and gave as input to Thrust's sort the `c` variable however it did not help.

On the other hand, using the constant memory gave a small improvement. My GPU has a 2_1 compatibility and I've heard that in 2_1 cache is used even for global memory maybe that's why I didn't see any significant improvement. Thank you very much for your help!